# android check heap memory in run time

Tags: android

I have an android app, this application connect to server to download images, but this images  has more than one copy, first copy 1600 * 1080 pixel and the second is 800 * 540 ...
so the device should send tag to server to download the good images for this device
I used many ways to check the device memory or density but the results was not clear enough to make a decision, here some code I used:

```
 float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 long mem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
 long heap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
```

the results was for 3 devices like this:

samsumg tab 10 inch = `1.0 , 745464 , 3249552 byte`

china tab 7 inch = `1.0 , 559944 , 2789016 byte`

htc moble 3.4 inch = `1.5 , 1760904 , 8942736 byte`

as the result showed the htc is the better but it was not because I can't view the highest resolution on it, but on the other devices it was very good
the error msg: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7687KB, Allocated=3356KB, Bitmap Size=25092KB)

Any help in this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decision should depend on two factors:

1. **Screen density.**
2. **Screen Size.**

In your case you had received hdpi drawables on htc, but it's small device, so it's not required to show large image with more details on small device.

for more information for loading large bitmaps efficiently:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html